# React Native npx create-react-app Problem

Tags: javascript, react-native

My PowerShell(Terminal) Warn, i don't used npm install or any one just tried npx create-react-app NKE command:

```
PS C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native> npx create-react-app NKE                                                                                                                                              
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-28T21_08_04_536Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native>
```

The Loc File:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.2.3
2 info using node@v20.10.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~\.npm-global'\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 9ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm exec create-react-app NKE
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "NKE"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-28T21_08_04_536Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-28T21_08_04_536Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 warn using --force Recommended protections disabled.
31 timing npm:load Completed in 39ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 7 files
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 306ms (cache revalidated)
36 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
37 timing command:exec Completed in 325ms
38 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~'
39 verbose cwd C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native
40 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
41 verbose node v20.10.0
42 verbose npm  v10.2.3
43 error code ENOENT
44 error syscall lstat
45 error path C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~
46 error errno -4058
47 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native\'~'
48 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
48 error enoent
49 verbose exit -4058
50 timing npm Completed in 673ms
51 verbose code -4058
52 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-28T21_08_04_536Z-debug-0.log
```

I need to create an app, how can i solve this problem, can someone help me?
I installed node and i added in System Environment Variable but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my computer and reinstalled everything and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

In order to create react-native app in Windows,  follow this:

If you are new to react-native then I would recommend to checkout react-native page for installation because they will give you to install easy way  => https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Here is a simplified version:

1. learn how to install npm package manager or node js related dependency
2. lean what are the dependency of  react-naive cli

Here is the  the another installation guide step-by-step:

1. install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en)
2. install [Python](https://www.python.org/)

   - Because React Native relies on Python 2, but it's recommended to use Python 3. Download and install Python from the official website:
3. [install JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/)

   - React Native requires Java to be installed. You can download and install the JDK from the official Oracle website
4. Install Yarn (Optional):
   Yarn is a package manager that can be used as an alternative to npm. You can install Yarn by following the instructions on their website:
5. Set up Environment Variables:

   - Add Node.js and Yarn to your system's PATH variable.
6. Install React native CLI:

   - use terminal to install

     ```bash
     npm install -g react-native-cli
     ```
7. Create a New React native project

   ```bash
   npx react-native init <your-project-name>
   ```

Comment: this command have issue: 
`PS C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native> npx react-native init NKE
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn terminal_path
npm ERR! path C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\React Native
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn terminal_path ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-29T19_56_59_084Z-debug-0.log`

Answer (score -1):

1. please check you have install node.js, npm  or not:

   ```bash
   node -v 
   npm -v
   ```

   - if they are facing any error then your  environment variable is not set maybe.
2. clear the npm cache by running the following command

   ```bash
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. try again to install react-native project

   ```bash
   npx react-native init <project-name>
   ```

Comment: Same issue continue

Comment: Why two answers? Would you mind removing recommendations and just focusing on answering the question?